# Feasibility of standard way of application deployment in different nodes using Kubernetes architecture

Tags: architecture, kubernetes

I am planning to use Kubernetes and Jenkins for my microservice deployment.

**Nature Of Application**

I have total 15 Spring Boot micro services. And need to deploy all these 15 micro services for different customers - everyone using same code, but need to deploy this all separately. Means every customer have their own deployed. Total I have 5 customer (This is assumption. Not exact one. It will varies from 20 to 50).

**My Current Design**

I am currently planning to use 5 Kubernetes Nodes.Means one cluster master plus 5 Node. Total 6 VMs. And planning to deploy each of these 15 micro services in these 5 nodes for 5 customer. So everyone will get their own deployment. And also I will install Jenkins in my Kubernetes cluster master VM for making a CI/CD pipeline.

So these about all architecture. I am only a starter in architecture and designing of cloud application. Here I need to know that any issues related with this architecture. I need to confirm its feasibility.

Please clear my confusion about my current approach. If this is a good one, I can continue. I am only searching this is a industrial standard way of using Kubernetes. Is this way a good architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things come to mind:

- one master is not enough. The loss of that VM, the underlying hardware, or a failure of the services on the master will lead to an outage for all customers, and potentially catastrophic data loss. Run 3 masters at minimum.
- each client running distinct copies of each of the services is a suboptimal tenancy model. There are lots of situations in which that's required, but in those situations each client is often running their own distinct release of the services. Managing that in a microservice architecture is awful.
- CD in an environment where each client is running their own copies of services, potentially their own versions of each, will be impossible.
- the JVM is a heavy CPU and memory consumer. A single JVM was designed to itself support multiple workloads. So there can be conflicts between container resource management and JVM resource management, and running JVM microservices

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. Its a great pleasure .I understood your points with suggestion to use 3 masters. Thanks. But according to your 3 rd and 4 th point , I have confusion again. Why you said deployment in this design get awful ? Then How I can manage my delivery / deployment in a proper way ? Since I am planning to use Jenkins here . I already configured one spring cloud config server with different profile for customers. I thought that I can launch application for each customers with their specific profile/configuration easily. Can you suggest one standard way to deploy ?

Comment: Here the code is same. When I am launching application I can launch for different customers as docker images.And when I am exploring I found that , I can use the Jenkins automated tool for building images and deployment also.  That the way currently I am planning to arrange this deployment. Let me know the points from your side sir ?

Comment: Happy to help, sir. Jenkins is fine for automation. The observations I'm making are more about the tenancy model. If each of 50 customers is running each of 15 applications, that's 750 application instances, 750 JVMs. Since sometimes applications and VMs and so forth fail, one might want to run 2 or 3 instances of each app- for each customer- to maintain SLAs. That's thousands of JVMs, which is a stretch for 5 VM nodes. In addition, each individual customer will certainly underutilize the resources provisioned for them, saddling the operator with high fixed costs.

Comment: The specific point about CD is really also about tenancy- performing continuous delivery on each customer's provisioned applications will be logistically complicated, since each application change will impact 50-100 instances. If multiple applications can be changed/delivered at a time, corner case errors will emerge for specific customers that will be hard to track down. My advice is really just that the tenancy model of application-instance-per-customer is much more expensive and complicated than the alternative.

Comment: Yes I understood your tenancy observation. But I did not understood your last statement - "My advice is really just that the tenancy model of application-instance-per-customer is much more expensive and complicated than the alternative". Can you clarify the statement sir please?

Comment: Are you saying that need to deploy application wise in nodes. Means If suppose I have one microservice  for user management.  So in one node , need to deploy that microservice in one node. application Instance for every customer will run in that node only. If new customer added in my project domain , I don't need to create another node. Since we can create that customer instance in the same node that we using for every customer.

Comment: So in my kubernetes cluster ,  Nodes are not representing customer. Its only representing my one application. If i have 1000 customer nodes count will not be varies, Since we are deploying in node as application oriented. Every customer instance will work in one node for one application. So scalability we can retain according with customer count.Is this model you are actually denoting?

Comment: Clarification in Stack Overflow comments is difficult, but the point is just- if I am understanding correctly- there are generally 2 tenancy options. One option is that all tenants use the same application instances- nothing unique is running for any one customer. That's generally operationally optimal. Another option is what it sounds like is being described above- each tenant gets their own running copy of each microservice. Sometimes this is necessary, but compared to the first option, over time this approach is much more expensive and complicated.

Comment: One can certainly scale to support additional customers by adding more application instances, but it's more complicated and expensive than the model where all customers share the same instances.

Comment: In your first point you said that , we need to use at least 3 masters in kubernetes cluster. If I am installing my Jenkins in any of one worker machine/node which belongs to one master , Then is there any problem for making Jenkins deployment in these all nodes ?. Means here I need to deploy all my docker images in all nodes which belongs to these 3 master by using Jenkins which installed in one worker machine / node?.

Comment: Jenkins will use a kubectl-like client to create Deployment and other resources in the cluster, and should talk to the load balancer sitting in front of the masters. When Deployment resources are created, kubelets running on the nodes will pull images from the registry for deployment on the nodes. So it doesn't precisely matter where Jenkins is running.

Comment: Just helpful information